# onClientClick for asp:element within a listview

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have these `asp:ImageButton`s: which are withing a listview

```
    <asp:ImageButton ID="profile" runat="server" Width="60px" Height="60px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("photo") %>'  OnClientClick="photoFrame()" CssClass="Frame" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="basic" runat="server" Width="60px" Height="60px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("photo") %>' OnClientClick="photoFrame()"/>
```

now when I click it, i want it to change it's border and the other's `asp:ImageButtons`'s border.

so here is `photoFrame()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function photoFrame() {
            document.getElementById("basic").setAttribute("CssClass", "Frame");
            document.getElementById("profile").removeAttribute("CssClass");
        }
</script>
```

but instead it does an error:

**Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.**

I have looked around the search for a solution and i came out with adding `enableEventValidation="false"` to the page's `<% %>`, but instead of doing the error it just does a postback and thats it.

How can i fix it? Thanks for the help

*I need the asp controls for the List's ItemDataBound function

so i could do this:

```
        var profile = e.Item.FindControl("profile") as ImageButton;
        var basic = e.Item.FindControl("basic") as ImageButton;
```

EDIT:
this problem is solved, all i did was to change it into asp:image and add the return false;.

```
    <asp:Image ID="profile" runat="server" Width="60px" Height="60px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("photo") %>'  OnClick="photoFrame();return false" CssClass="Frame"/>
    <asp:Image ID="basic" runat="server" Width="60px" Height="60px" OnClick="photoFrame();return false"/>
```

but now i guess that the commands in the function `photoFrame()` doesnt work  because it doesnt do anything, but when i change it to alert(something) for example it does work.

do you know other way to change an asp:element's attribute in javascript?

i tried

```
    document.getElementById('basic').className='Frame';
document.getElementById('profile').className='';
```

and it didnt do anything also.

Maby i cant getElementById an elemt that is within a listview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `return false` to your on `OnClientClick` declaration:

```
OnClientClick="photoFrame();return false"
```

it will cancel the postback, but still execute the client-side function.

But in reality, since you don't really need an actual button, you can replace `asp:ImageButton` with `asp:Image` and just use `onclick` attribute.

Also - since your JS function is dealing with client-side elements the attribute you want to set or remove is "class", not "CssClass" (which is used by server-side controls)

Comment: It didnt work adding the return false, and i need the asp controls for the List's ItemDataBound function

Comment: Please define " didn't work" return false if implemented as shown above should cancel postback. Also asp:Image *is* ASP.NET control.

Comment: Alright Thanks!,with the asp:Image it doesnt do postback. then i guess the problem is in what in the function because it doesnt do anything, but when i change it to alert(something) for example it does work. do you know other way to change an asp:element's attribute in javascript?

Comment: Also note that IDs of images may have changed within ListView. You can verify this by viewing HTML source

Comment: Yuriy Glanter you were right, the listview changed the id of the img, so i checked the new id in the html source, used it and it worked!Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You appear to not want the imagebuttons to fire a server request but only call the photoFrame function.
Replace the imagebuttons with img tags and give them onclick event handlers.

Which ever solution you choose, I think you need to change your javascript function to:

```
document.getElementById('basic').className='Frame';
document.getElementById('profile').className='';
```

Add this:

```
<asp:Literal id="basic" text="<img src=\"photo\" width=\"60\" height=\"60\" onclick=\"photoFrame();\"/>" runat="server"/>
```

If this doesn't do the trick, it means there's something else at fault here.

Comment: Is it possible to add HTML elements within a literal control?

Comment: i have changed it to asp:image element and now it does get into the fnction but the commands in it dont do anything, is there other way to control asp:element from javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your `ImageButton` asp controls.

This will keep the `ID`s of the controls static so your function will be able to target the intended elements, otherwise `.net` will alter the `ID`s based on your markup structure and your script will not target the elements.

Comment: I have just added ClientIDMode="Static" to the ImageButton as you said, if that's only it. and it didnt work